# Acturial Studies: what is the formula for compound discount with simpe discount over the final fractional period?

Tags: finance

What is the formula for compound discount with simple discount over the fractional period. I could not find the formula in my book and when I looked online the ones that had the formula where answers to a question in my book which I did not want to see the answer in order to get the formula. The formulas that I know are: Note that $d$ stands for the discount rate.

$a(t)^{-1}=(1-d)^t$ for compound discount

$a(t)^{-1}=(1-dt)$

$d_{m}=\frac{i_{m}}{1+i_{m}}$

I am wondering why no one has answered am I asking a question that does not make sense?

Edit: my question is in response to the following:

Method A assumes simple interest over final fractional periods, while Method B assumes simple discount over final fractional periods. The annual effective rate of interest is 20%. Find the ratio of the present value of a payment made in $1.5$ years computed under Method A to that computed under Method B

Comment: You mean that the period interest is $i_m=\frac{i}{m}$? Isn´t then $d_m=\frac{i_m}{1+i_m}$?

Comment: yes I suppose so. Why is no one answering?

Comment: Maybe your question is not clear enough. Do you have an example?

Comment: sure but I do not want the answer. This is based off a question in a textbook I am studying

Comment: @callculus I have edited my question and provided the question

Comment: Does simple discount corresponds with simple interest (in contrast to compound interest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *d* be the discount rate, *t* be the total time of investment, and *k* be the largest integer such that *t* > *k* .  First we calculate the compound interest over time *k*, then multiply that by the simple interest for time *t-k*.  Thus your accumulation function is:

$ a(t) = (1 -d)^{-k} (1-d(t-k))  $

Similarly, the accumulation function for compound interest with interest rate *i* :

$ a(t) = (1 + i)^k (1 + it) $

Bonus points if you don't forget to take $ (a(t))^{-1} $ for present value in your question like I did.